# Angular how to read an excel file from an assets folder using typeScript

Tags: excel, angular, typescript

Ashamed to ask, but for resolving my problem I need to ask.
So, I have a problem with reading data from an excel file in my Angular project. The file is located in the *assets* folder.

I know how to get a file from the folder.

In **app.component.ts** inside **ngOnInit** I get a file:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get('assets/dataTest.xlsx').subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log("get: " + data);
  });
}
```

How I understand inside **http.get** I need to use code below:

```
const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (e: any) => {
  console.log("READ " + e);
};
reader.readAsBinaryString(data);
```

But it does not work. I get an error:

> ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Help me please with reading data from an **excel** file is located in the *assets* folder.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a library to parse the excel file.

See there an example of [SheetJs](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/tree/a81bb78f18960053a03bb3350f31ea54d28245be/demos/angular2):

```
/* <input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple="false" /> */
/* ... (within the component class definition) ... */
  onFileChange(evt: any) {
    /* wire up file reader */
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* read workbook */
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});

      /* grab first sheet */
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      /* save data */
      this.data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header: 1}));
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
  }
```

Comment: In my project, I use this library. I need to open the file along with the web page loading. Your example works only with events (click to a button).

Comment: Hey, i was looking for https://www.onooks.com/angular-7-not-able-to-read-excel-file-from-assets-folder/ maybe you are too...

Answer (score 0):

i just solve the problem with this.

```
read() {
this.httpClient.get('assets/files/Report DTP.xls', { responseType: 'blob' })
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

    let dataJson1;
    let dataJson2;

    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });

      /* grab first sheet */
      const wsname1: string = wb.SheetNames[1];
      const ws1: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname1];

      /* grab second sheet */
      const wsname2: string = wb.SheetNames[2];
      const ws2: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname2];

      /* save data */
      dataJson1 = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws1);
      dataJson2 = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws2);
      console.log(dataJson1);

    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(data);
    console.log(data);
  });
```

}

I hope it helps you even though it's late :)